# Mediation R package p-values: workaround to get more significant digits?

Tags: r, trace

I am running multiple mediation analyses and need to correct for multiple comparisons. However, the p-values provided by the mediation package appear to be stored already rounded, as observed in the very helpful answer by @Roland on this question:

[R mediation package : digit behind comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53850958/r-mediation-package-digit-behind-comma)

Has anyone found a workaround to actually pull out more significant digits for the pvalues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are being printed with 2 digits, because that's all the method computes. It's a randomized analysis, so the p-value is just the fraction out of 50 (in the referenced answer) of the simulations that met some condition.  If you want more digits, you'll need to run with `sims` set to a much larger value than 50.  After you do that, you can probably change the digits setting using the same technique as in that post, or more simply as follows:

1. Execute this:

   print.summary.mediate <- mediation:::print.summary.mediate
2. Use fix(print.summary.mediate) to edit the source, and change the line

   printCoefmat(smat, digits = 3)

to whatever desired number of digits you want.  I chose 6.

Then run the code:

```
data(jobs)
b <- lm(job_seek ~ treat + econ_hard + sex + age, data=jobs)
c <- lm(depress2 ~ treat + job_seek + econ_hard + sex + age, data=jobs)
 
contcont <- mediate(b, c, sims=1000, treat="treat", mediator="job_seek")
summary(contcont)
```

I got this output:

```
Causal Mediation Analysis 

Quasi-Bayesian Confidence Intervals

                 Estimate 95% CI Lower 95% CI Upper p-value
ACME           -0.0166933   -0.0404983      0.00735   0.168
ADE            -0.0412011   -0.1278011      0.04465   0.348
Total Effect   -0.0578944   -0.1449898      0.02716   0.196
Prop. Mediated  0.2313315   -1.7557486      1.89099   0.288

Sample Size Used: 899 


Simulations: 1000
```

You only see 3 digits on the p-values, because that's all you get with 1000 simulations: `n/1000` always has 3 digits.  If you choose `sims` to be something that's not a round number,
you'll see more digits:  but the later ones will be worthless, they don't really signify anything other than the fact that a fraction like 123/456 doesn't have a nice decimal expansion.

Yours will be different, because it's a randomized analysis.

Comment: I'm kicking myself for not having realized this was the problem, but you are spot on, and I am most appreciative!